# I need help in solving this recurrence

Tags: math, recurrence

I have been trying to solve this recurrence for almost 2 hours but could not get the answer...

**Let:**

```
T(n)= kn+T(n/2) for n>1 and T(1)=1 where n = 2^k for some integer k
```

Show that T(n)= O(n)

Comment: Is the k in kn the same as n = 2^k?

Comment: It would be a right candidate for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming the *k* in T(n) = kn + T(n / 2) is not the same as the k in n = 2^k.  If that's wrong, I'll update this.)

If you just need an asymptotic bound, then you can use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).  Your recurrence is

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + kn

So a = 1, b = 2, and c = 1.  Therefore, since log<sub>b</sub> a = 0 < 1, the Master Theorem causes this to solve to Θ(n).

If you need an exact value, you can use the iteration method to get a good guess.  I'm assuming T(1) = 1.

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + kn
>
> = (T(n / 4) + kn/2) + kn
>
> = T(n / 4) + kn + kn/2
>
> = (T(n / 8) + kn / 4) + kn + kn / 2
>
> = T(n / 8) + kn + kn / 2 + kn / 4
>
> ...
>
> = T(n / 2<sup>i</sup>) + kn(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2<sup>i</sup>)

This terminates when i = log<sub>2</sub> n, at which point we get

> T(n) = T(1) + kn(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n)
>
> = 1 + kn(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n)
>
> = 2kn

So the exact figure should be (modulo math errors) 2kn, agreeing with the result from the Master Theorem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your quick response! It was not mention if the K is same or not! How did you come up with the 'C' value even though it is not asymptotic ?

Comment: What C value are you referring to?

Comment: in your answer you have identified a, b and c to apply the Master Theorem. According to my book, c has to be something like O(n), Θ(n) something like that.

Comment: @FaisalAbdullah- Ah, okay.  The version of the Master Theorem I'm using is from Wikipedia (link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) and the c is the exponent on the last term.  Here, kn = Theta(n) = Theta(n^1), so c = 1.